# Float division of big numbers in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two big numbers `a` and `b` of length around 10000, such that `a <= b`.
Now, I have to find `c = a / b`, upto 10 places of decimal, how do I do it without loosing precision?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/decimal.html).

Comment: Another alternative would be to use the [mpmath](http://mpmath.org) module.

Comment: a and b both are LONG INT.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `decimal` module:

```
from decimal import localcontext, Decimal

def foo(a, b):
    with localcontext() as ctx:
        ctx.prec = 10   # Sets precision to 10 places temporarily
        c = Decimal(a) / Decimal(b) # Not sure if this is precise if a and b are floats, 
                                    # str(a) and str(b) instead'd ensure precision i think.
    return float(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `decimal` module should work. As seen in TigerhawkT3's link, you can choose the number of decimal places your quotient should be.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 6
a = float(raw_input('The first number:'))       #Can be int() if needed
b = float(raw_input('The second number:'))
c = Decimal(a) / Decimal(b)
print float(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate any type of length float number with this function

```
def longdiv(divisor,divident):
    quotient,remainder=divmod(divisor,divident)
    return (str(quotient)+str(remainder*1.0/divident)[1:])
```